# Aframe execute component code on load of children

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have something like this setup in my code:

```
<a-entity id="foo-parent" rotation="0 15 0" my-component>
         
<a-entity gltf-model="#foo" id="foo0"></a-entity>
<a-entity gltf-model="#foo" id="foo1"></a-entity>
<a-entity gltf-model="#foo" id="foo2"></a-entity>
<a-entity gltf-model="#foo" id="foo3"></a-entity>
<a-entity gltf-model="#foo" id="foo4"></a-entity>

</entity>
```

And my component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('my-component', {
  schema: {
    img: {
      default: ["tex_0","tex_1","tex_2","tex_3","tex_4"]
    }
  },
  init: function() {
    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;

      el.addEventListener('loaded', function(e) {
        // setTimeout(function() {
          el.object3D.traverse(function(child) {
            console.log(child);
            if (child.isMesh) {
              var picker = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.img.length);
              // console.log(picker);
              var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('./images/'+data.img[picker]+'.jpg');
              console.log(data.img[picker]);
              child.idNum = data.img[picker].split("_")[1];
              console.log(child.idNum); // need to set reference to img

              child.material.map = texture;
              child.material.map.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
              child.material.map.flipY = false;
              data.img.splice(picker,1);

            }
          });
        // },2000);

  }
});
```

My issue is that if I don't have that 2000ms setTimeout within the loaded eventListener I don't get the images applied to the meshes - it's as if the child models are still loading and therefore cannot get the image mapped contrary to what is outlined here https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/asset-management-system.html.

Comment: Without code to run and debug it will be hard to help. I recommend sharing simple code that illustrates the question with glitch.com/~aframe

Answer (score 0):

The `loaded` event is emitted once an entity has [attached and initialized it's components](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/entity.html#events_loaded)(where initialized is calling init() in the components).

It won't wait until all children are loaded - it needs to be done manually - especially if there is some resource loading involved, like in the case of loading gltf models.

You can just count `model-loaded` events to know if all is ready:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    var counter = 0;
    // iterate through the children
    for (let child of this.el.children) {
      // when the model is loaded - increment the counter
      child.addEventListener("model-loaded", e => {
        if (counter++ >= this.el.children.length) {
          // all is loaded - do your magic
          this.childrenLoaded.call(this)
        }
      })
    }
  },
  childrenLoaded: function() {
    // do your stuff
  }
})
```

Example of changing colors when all children are loaded [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/models/child_models.html)([source](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/master/aframe/models/child_models.html))